# hyperref - print \today as pdftitle in languages other than English

Tags: hyperref, languages

I have a problem with `hyperref`: it does not take into account the language when I use the macro `\today` in my `pdftitle`. In fact, I use this macro in other pdf fields too.

**The date in the  `pdftitle` remains in english.**

I compile with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}


%%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}


%%%% \usepackage{alternative4ht}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{czech}



\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdfencoding=auto,
psdextra,
pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,
}

\hypersetup{
pdftitle={\today.},
}

\begin{document}
\today

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\hypersetup{pdftitle=\today}` is too early, since the language isn't set at that time.

However, `\hypersetup` can be used just before `\begin{document}` with `\AtBeginDocument` hook. Since there's no other hook defined, this is the last one being executed and at this time of compilation the language settings are done.

This gives the correct output of `\today` for `pdftitle` then.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}


%%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}


%%%% \usepackage{alternative4ht}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
%  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{czech}



\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfencoding=auto,
  psdextra,
  pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,
}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{pdftitle=\today}
} 


\begin{document}
\today
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\today}

\end{document}
```

[image]